# Entity Framework not caching objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got a list of "cases" using a stored procedure.

```
List<Case> tmp = context.Case_Search(Query).ToList();
```

When i display this list on the page it references a linked table called "CaseContacts" this makes EF run an SQL statement for each case.

As i can't use include on a stored procedure i've tried to pre-load the linked objects using:

```
int[] ids = tmp.Select(x => x.ID).ToArray();
CaseContact[] CCs = context.CaseContacts.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.CaseID)).ToArray();
```

However EF is still going to the DB for each linked CaseContact.

Do i need to tell EF to use the cached version? I assumed if the object had previously been loaded EF would use the object rather than another trip to the DB.

**Update:**

I've changed my code to switch off lazy loading before i run my code and to switch it back on afterwards and it seems to do what i expect 1-2 sql trips instead of 200+.

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
List<Case> tmp = context.Case_Search(Query).ToList();
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

It doesn't even need the extra query to load the linked property.  Any downsides to this?

Comment: Until you really know you want it, I would recommend turning off `LazyLoadingEnabled` in general.